# Alternative for *Ngfor components

Tags: angular5, ngfor

Is there a better solution for this, in Angular 5?

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components | async">
    <component-1  *ngIf="component.type === 'some-type-1'"></component-1>
    <component-2  *ngIf="component.type === 'some-type-2'"></component-2>
    <component-3  *ngIf="component.type === 'some-type-3'"></component-3>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create another list containing the types, and with a second *ngFor loop, you compare the types

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use a custom pipe to filter the components based on type. You can obviously customise your pipe to better suit your components' properties.

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components | myfilter: 'some-type-1'">
    <component-1></component-1>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let component of components | myfilter: 'some-type-2'">
    <component-2></component-2>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let component of components | myfilter: 'some-type-3'">
    <component-3></component-3>
</div>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ml4whk)